# How to re-load camera after capturing an image in surfaceview android?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

i am creating an app where i am using camera in surfaceview. The problem is after taking the picture in camera, it keeps on showing the taken picture unable to take next one, but the captured image gets stored in the filepath. What i need is after capturing an image in surfaceview it should automatically re-load the camera to take the next one.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);

        }
    });

    }

SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;

    }
};

Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera1) {

        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                data.length);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture, 0, 0,
                bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Date d = new Date();
          CharSequence dateOfShot  = DateFormat.format("ddMMyyhhmmss", d.getTime());

        String fname = "Image-" + dateOfShot + ".jpg";

        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewHolder.removeCallback(surfaceCallback);
        camera.release();
        camera = Camera.open();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);         
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add

```
camera.startPreview();
```

to the end of onPictureTaken method

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    //your existing code here

    camera.startPreview();
}
```

because of [takePicture behavior](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)):

> This method is only valid when preview is active (after startPreview()). Preview will be stopped after the image is taken; callers must call startPreview() again if they want to re-start preview or take more pictures. This should not be called between start() and stop().
>
> After calling this method, you must not call startPreview() or take another picture until the JPEG callback has returned.

Comment: When control goes over the `onPictureTaken()` method, the `GLSurfaceView` gets black showing that the image is capturing. I don't want to show the black, i want show the captured image on/over the `GLSurfaceView`. how can is possible?

Comment: i do exastly same but now problem is it shows me blur image

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart the preview: camera.startPreview();

Comment: try putting it after: public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);

        }
    });

Comment: app gets crashed on adding camera.startpreview after onclick method.

Comment: try to add the camera.startPreview() after: Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera1) {

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
package com.example.videostreamer;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
Context mContext;
private static final String TAG = "Camera Preview";
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mContext = context;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    //deprecated setting required in prior to android 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // if your preview can change or rotate, take care of this events here
    // make sure stop preview before resizing or reformatting.

    // stop preview before change
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Error in Surface Changed :"+e.getMessage());
    }
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.



    // start preview with new settings
    try{
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error in Surface Changed"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Error in Surface Created :" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

This code work fine for camera application.

after picture taken called release camera & removeallview from preview

```
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

            /* set image preview in imageview */
            previewImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewPrieview);
            previewImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));

            /* release camera & removeallview from preview */
            relaese();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

  private void relaese(){
    mCamera.release();
    preview.removeAllViews();
   /* then call again take preview */
    take_priview();
  }
  private void take_priview(){
    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.CapturePreview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

  }
```